# VB.Net Timer3 Control is not stopping usin stop method

Tags: vb.net, timer

I have used three timers in my program. All are working fine except the third one. i don't know why?

```
 Private Sub Timer3_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer3.Tick
    MessageBox.Show("dont repeat please")
    Timer3.Stop()

End Sub
```

In the form_load i had started the timer, but its showing message box again and again at the interval of 3000ms which i have set. Please help.

Comment: How is the timer being started?

Comment: Stop the timer **before** you display the message box.  If you don't then you'll just fill up the screen with message boxes that you can't click fast enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless there is more to it a quick solution is to just move the call stop the timer to before the message box.

```
Private Sub Timer3_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer3.Tick
    Timer3.Stop()
    MessageBox.Show("dont repeat please")
End Sub
```

Basically the processing of the code in the Timer3_Ticket sub is being blocked by the display of the message box. The timer running on another thread will continue to raise tick events at each time interval until a message box is closed and the stop method is called.